# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед "согласно" в предложении "Услуга по предоставлению справочной информации согласно договору №1 от 01 Февраля 2000 года"?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, в этом предложении нет никаких причин для постановки запятой. "Согласно" можно заменить предлогом "по"

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Ваш ответ мне очень помог.

Answer (score 1):

Запятую ставить не нужно. Обороты с предлогом СОГЛАСНО часто обособляются, но не всегда, все зависит от структуры предложения (заменой на предлог ПО как раз и проверяется эта структура). Сравнить: Поезд будет отправлен согласно расписанию (оборот входит в основное сообщение) Поезд, согласно расписанию, отправляется через час (обособленный оборот в добавочном сообщении, удобная для обособления позиция между подлежащим и сказуемым). Также из художественной прозы:   Жениховой родне, согласно уговору, поднесли три рюмки водки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вы очень помогли. Я сразу вспомнила этот метод проверки.